# Melee system in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, scripting

I'm new to unity and programming. I'm trying to make me fight in the first game in unity. Can you help me? I tried a tutorial from this guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWQlNztOoSM, but I get a lot of errors in his script.

Comment: So fix the first episode error. Repeat until all errors have gone

Comment: For future reference, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup in one of my projects.

Player:

Set up the player's attack animations to call Attack at the start and StopAttack at the end
See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html

supposing rightHand is the parent Transform of the weapon, you can activate your weapons. Add these methods to your player's script:

```
    public void Attack()
    {
        foreach (Weapon w in rightHand.GetComponentsInChildren<Weapon>())
        {
            w.Attack();
        }
    }
    //called by animations
    public void StopAttack()
    {
        foreach (Weapon w in rightHand.GetComponentsInChildren<Weapon>())
        {
            w.StopAttack();
        }
    }
```

Weapon: add a collider and check "Is Trigger"

My enemies all have a class called "badguy" that can take damage with badguy.Damage(float amount). "mask" is for optimization and should be set to the layer of the enemies. If you are unsure, set mask to everything.

```
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
...
{
    public LayerMask mask
    public float dmg;
    private bool canDmg;
    public float attackDuriation;
    private float timeSinceAttack;

    void Update()
    {
        timeSinceAttack += Time.deltaTime;
        if(timeSinceAttack > attackDuriation)
        {
            canDmg = false;
        }
    }

    public void Attack()
    {
        canDmg = true;
        timeSinceAttack = 0;
    }

    public void StopAttack()
    {
        canDmg = false;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (canDmg)
        {
            if(mask == (mask | (1 << other.gameObject.layer)))//if included in the mask
            {
                badguy bg = other.GetComponentInParent<badguy>();
                if(bg != null)
                {
                    bg.Damage(dmg);
                    canDmg = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```